# I want to display the message when I push send button. And want be reset message form

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, email

I am making a contact form using React.js and emailjs, but I input a form that says "Message sent !!" after sending a message and "Failed to send message!" When the message cannot be sent. I'd like to make it appear on the top, but I'm a little stucking in the CSS styling method at that time.

JS

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
    import "./Contact.css";
    import { init, send } from 'emailjs-com';
    init('MY USER ACCOUNT');
    
    const Contact = () => {
    
      const [contactNumber, setContactNumber] = useState('000000')
      const [statusMessage, setStatusMessage] = useState('message')
      const generateContactNumber = () => {
        const numStr = '000000' + (Math.random() * 1000000 | 0);
        setContactNumber(numStr.substring(numStr.length - 6))
      }

  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const form = document.querySelector('#contact-form')
    generateContactNumber();
    send('service', 'template', data)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
        setStatusMessage("Message sent!!")
        statusMessage.className = 'status-message success' 
        setTimeout(() => {
          statusMessage.className = 'status-message'
        }, 5000)
        form.reset();


      }, function (error) {
        console.log('FAILED...', error);
        setStatusMessage('Failed to send message! Please try again :-(')
        statusMessage.className = "status-message failure"
        setTimeout(() => {
          statusMessage.className = 'status-message'
        }, 5000)
      })
  }

  const message = watch('message') || "";
  const messageCharsLeft = 1500 - message.length;

  return (

    <body>
    
      <div className="Contact" >
        <h1>Contact me</h1>
        <p>Please talk me any question if you have </p>
        <p className="status-message">{statusMessage}</p>
      </div>

      <form id='contact-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} >
        <input type='hidden' name='contact_number' value={contactNumber} />

        {errors.user_name && errors.user_name.type === "required" && (
          <div role="alert">Name is required<br /></div>)}
        <input type='text' name='user_name' placeholder='Name' maxLength='30'
          aria-invalid={errors.user_name ? "true" : "false"}{...register("user_name", ({ required: true }))} />
        <br />

        {errors.user_email && errors.user_email.type === "required" && (
          <div role="alert">Email is required<br /></div>)}
        <input type='email' name='user_email' placeholder='Email'{...register("user_email", ({ required: true }))} />
        <br />

        {errors.message && errors.message.type === "required" && (
          <div role="alert">Message is required<br /></div>)}
        <textarea name='message' {...register("message", ({ required: true }))} placeholder='Message' maxLength='1500' />
        {/* <p className='message-chars-left'>{messageCharsLeft}</p> */}
        <br />

        <input type='submit' className="submit" value='Send' />
      </form>
      
    </body>
  )
}
```

CSS

```
body{
  background-color: black;
 
}


input, textarea{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 600px;
  
}

textarea {
  height: 10em;
  width: 600px;
}

div[role='alert'] {
  color: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: larger;
}

.message-chars-left {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.Contact h1{
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
  'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
  sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-weight:900;
}
.Contact p{
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
  'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
  sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
}

.submit:hover{
  background:rgb(176, 180, 180);
  transition: 0.5 s;
}

.status-message {
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  transition: 0.3;
}

.success{
  opacity: 1;
  color: green;
}

.failure{ 
  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
  .Contact h1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: x-large;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
  .Contact p {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: x-large;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
  input{
    width: 360px;
    
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
  textarea {
    width: 360px;
    
  }
}
```

When I run it with the code above, the .status-message css seems to be working and the text doesn't appear in the form, but when I cut the wifi beforehand and send it ("Failed to send message "I want to show the message"! ...) The .failure css doesn't work and nothing shows up.
When I set the opacity of .status-message to 1 and do the same thing, it shows "message" on the form before submitting and changes to "Failed to send message!..." after submitting. ..
So I think the function itself is done, but it's chock full of how to make css work.
Also, when I try to send it, I get the error "Uncaught type error (in promise): Cannot create property 'class name' on string 'message'" in the check console, but it works.
and, use reset() on .then so that Form can return the form to the state before the message was entered after submission, but the message remains even after submission.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `.className` property on a string, and strings doesn't have that property. So that's why you get the type error. It only stops the execution of your eventhandler and thus. Per example, does your form reset on success? It shouldn't.

What you need to do instead, is to introduce some new boolean states, one for success and one for errors. Now in the `<p>` tag that contains your status message, test for those booleans. If success is true, apply the success class to the `<p>` tag. Same thing for errors.

Comment: Yes you are right. Finally I used just two booleans in there.Now it work!! Thank you so much!!